# Resizing floated elements, that are resizable with JQuery UI Resizable, on window resize to fit their parent container

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-float, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm having trouble to solve an issue with floated elements and  JQuery UI Resizable and window resize event.

Here is the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxVPq/116/)** with the problem.

Basically, I have a parent container - .tab - and 3 child divs. .content1, .content2 and .content3. Both .content2 and content3 are inversely proportional resized when .content1 is resized with the "alsoInverResize" function.

```
<div class="tab">
    <div class="container1"></div>
    <div class="container2"></div>
    <div class="container3"></div>
</div>

$(".container1").resizable({
    containment: "parent",
    handles: "s",
    alsoInverResize: ".container2, .container3",
    maxHeight: $(".tab").height()
});
```

Althought all 3 child divs start with percentage widths and height to fit their parent, when they're resized they get flat sizes, and when you resize the window to less than the original size, they overflow from the parent container, making the .container3 floating left under .container2, or having less width that their parent if the window gets a bigger size than the original.

I've tried to set percentage sizes again on the window resize event, but that prevents the resizeable plugin from even working, obviously not being the desired effect (http://jsfiddle.net/fh77N/2/) :

```
$(".container1").css({"height" : "50%", "width" : "100%"});
$(".container3").css({"height" : "50%", "width" : "70%"});
$(".container2").css({"height" : "50%", "width" : "30%"});
```

I want to make the three child containers be either equality resized to the ratio of the window or parent on window.resize or having them revert to their original percentage sizes but maintaining the resizeable functionality.

Comment: Looks like the JSFiddle is working well to me...  When I re-size the output window, the sizes re-adjust and fill the entire area, and it appears to do this with the same proportions that are originally laid out.

Comment: You need to first resize the first child container (that can be resized in the south border between the bottom two) and then resize the window area of the jsFiddle. Notice now the containers don't resize, as the resizeable plugin assign them flat sizes to their styles.